# Register new constraint validator for standard bean validation annotation

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm wondering whether it's possible to register new constraint validator of some custom type to a annotation defined by Bean Validation specification.
For example, let's image I have a class that accumulates several int values

```
public class IntContainer
{
  private int value1;
  private int value2;


  public int getValue1()
  {
    return value1;
  }


  public void setValue1(final int value1)
  {
    this.value1 = value1;
  }


  public int getValue2()
  {
    return value2;
  }


  public void setValue2(final int value2)
  {
    this.value2 = value2;
  }
}
```

I would like to register a custom constraint validator to support the @Positive annotation for this type (instead of created a custom annotation).

```
public class PositiveIntContainerValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Positive, IntContainer>
{
  @Override
  public boolean isValid(final IntContainer value, final ConstraintValidatorContext context)
  {
    //TODO: do some validation here based on IntContainer state
    return false;
  }
}
```

So that later I can use this:

```
@Positive
private IntContainer valueContainer;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A fully qualified name of your validator can be added to `META-INF/services/javax.validation.ConstraintValidator` file. This would allow Hibernate Validator to pick up your validator and it will be used for your custom types.

See more details if needed in this [post](http://in.relation.to/2017/03/02/adding-custom-constraint-definitions-via-the-java-service-loader/) (section "Use standard constraints for non standard classes")

Comment: In Jakarta Bean Validation 3.0 (used eg. by Spring Boot 3.0) the file is named differently `jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidator`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use the @Positive annotation on your IntContainer class, as the validator does not support this data type.

Supported types for the @Positive annotation are:

- BigDecimal
- BigInteger
- byte, short, int, long, float, double and their respective wrappers

See [Annotation Type Positive](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/2.0/api/javax/validation/constraints/Positive.html).

You have two options here, you could write your own custom validator for IntContainer, or you could get the IntContainer from an entity that has it has a member variable and then validate it. Such as:

Bean:
    public class IntContainer {

```
@Positive
private int value1;
@Positive
private int value2;

public IntContainer() {

}

public IntContainer(int value1, int value2) {
    this.value1 = value1;
    this.value2 = value2;
}

public int getValue1() {
    return value1;
}

public void setValue1(final int value1) {
    this.value1 = value1;
}


public int getValue2() {
    return value2;
}


public void setValue2(final int value2) {
    this.value2 = value2;
}

}
```

Rest:

```
@POST
public Response postTest(TestRest testRest) {
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

    Set<ConstraintViolation<IntContainer>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(testRest.getIntContainer());
    System.out.println(constraintViolations.size());

    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(constraintViolations.size()).build();
}
```

Comment: That was the goal of my question :) Following the answer provided by 
@mark_o I've managed to do it.